# Google Play store Managed Publishing: Does a published Closed test version that is promoted go live immediately?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Trying to time a release exactly to match iOS store. I have a reviewed and published Closed Test track. A few questions, which I have been unable to find a definitive answer to:

1. Does promoting to Production go through review again? Lots of conflicting information about this one.
2. After promoting to Production, irrespective of the above, is the app Published to the store (with or without review), or does it go back into the Managed Publishing flow, and I have to click Publish before it goes to the store?

Basically I want to know if I should promote the release now, in case it does need to be reviewed again, knowing that it WILL NOT be live on the store, I have to click Publish before a Closed Test track published version that has been promoted goes live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both Cases the app will be reviewed but the only difference is if you want to publish it automatically after reviewing or you need to do it manually so answering to your questions:

1.Does promoting to Production go through review again? Lots of conflicting information about this one.

**ANSWER: *YES***

2.After promoting to Production, irrespective of the above, is the app Published to the store (with or without review), or does it go back into the Managed Publishing flow, and I have to click Publish before it goes to the store?

ANSWER: ***YES*
The app will be reviewed again
If you choose the Managed Publishing so you need to publish it manually
after being reviewed and approved ,
otherwise if you turn it off, the app will be published automatically after
being reviewed and approved**

Comment: Thanks, I ran it, and the above was exactly correct. Only slightly interesting thing was the review between Closed Test track and Production only took about 20 minutes.